# import error for pyautogui

Tags: python, import, module, pyautogui

I installed the pyautogui module and dependencies via pip-3.2 on my raspi correctly, However when I am trying to do

```
import pyautogui
```

I am getting an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named pyautogui
```

What am I doing wrong? Did the command change?
Sorry I am a total python Noob, any help is greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It might be because you're trying it from a python 2.x shell. Instead try this command on a python3 shell and try importing the same.

Answer (score 20):

True you would have to use python 3. First you have to make sure you checked the change system path variable while installing python 3. then open the command prompt on windows and type

```
pip install pyautogui
```

or

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

in osx and linux.

Comment: worked also for me using windows

Answer (score 10):

I also had a hard time getting pyautogui to work via Terminal on my macOS Catalina. I installed it using `pip3 install pyautogui`. It supposedly installed but still gave error: **No module named 'pyautogui'**, when I tried to import it (after running python3). What finally worked was this command I found on the pyautogui documentation page (https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html):

```
python3 -m pip install pyautogui
```

If it says permission denied, try:

```
python3 -m pip install --user pyautogui
```

Comment: It did not install correctly using `pip install pyautogui` but did install correctly using `python -m pip install` (not python3)

Answer (score 5):

Search in C:\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages (Where-ever you have installed it). Check if you have **pyautogui** directory.

If **YES** then there exists a configuration issue with **pycharm** or **IDLE**.

If **NO** then

- Open Command Prompt
- cd `C:\Python37-32\Scripts`
- `pip install pillow`
- `pip install pyautogui`

Check for **Successfully installed** response.

HAPPY CODING! :)

Comment: pip install pillow was the last thing I needed to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
# using py alias (Windows)
py -m pip install pyautogui
```

Source: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-pyautogui

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

If you run your script with sudo, you should install the module also under sudo...