# Unable to import pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have read [import error for pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635140/import-error-for-pyautogui)
and this did not answer my question.
I am trying to import pyautogui via the 3.5.2 shell or windows cmd. but when using the shell for:
import pyautogui

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui

ImportError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

I have seen people say they resolved by using 3.5 but not for me. I have also seen people say that uninstalling and reinstalling can fix issues. I did this and on reinstall made sure that the path option was selected.

Comment: Did you use `pip3 install pyautogui` to install PyAutoGUI?

Answer (score 2):

- Step one: open windows cmd
- Step two: and type in `py -3.8 -m pip install pyautogui`

You will most likely get a message that says: `pip is not up to date`, it would look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOfzQ.png
if you get this `error Type in: py -m pip install --upgrade pip`

- Step three: Open: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and copy everything on this page
- Step four: Open IDLE and run what you just copied
- Step five: Open windows cmd again and try `py -3.8 -m pip install pyautogui` again
- Step six: Now try to run it again.

if this doesnt work please show us the errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are installing the package using the correct Python Version, in the documentation says that you have to install correspondant to your python version. In my case, I fixed it using python 3.9 (and making sure that my intepreter in VSC is set to Python 3.9.1)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `pip install pyautogui` and if it says all requirements are satisfied type in `pip show pyautogui` and if it shows then just try restarting your IDE and it should work