# Pyautogui could not be resolved

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have installed pyautogui using `py -m pip install pyautogui` and it did say the install was successful.

But when i try importing it into my testing project with `import pyautogui as auto` in vscode it says

> Import "pyautogui" could not be resolved |*Pylance (reportMissingImports)*|

I have seen people having the same issue but i haven't found any fix yet.

I am a bit of a noob at python so sorry if i'm missing something super obvious.

Someone said that this post could fix my problem [Unable to import pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479179/unable-to-import-pyautogui)
but it did not. Now that i tried doing what this link says, i get four of these errors WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479179/unable-to-import-pyautogui)