# PYTHON: How do you run your programs from the terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, pycharm

I wrote this program that controls your computer to collect data from a website in the PyCharm IDE with python 3.7. In my program I imported different libraries like pyautogui.

```
import pyautogui, time, re, os


def process():
    # The rest of the code
```

Auto is the project name I have all the files in. I want to run the program from my terminal without having to run it from PyCharm but I'm getting these errors in it:

```
    laptop:auto user$ python ./test.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "./test.py", line 1, in <module>
            import pyautogui, time, re, os
    ImportError: No module named pyautogui
```

I downloaded Pyautogui onto my laptop using pip but I don't know how to make it so that the terminal can use the library. Any suggestions on what I should do to solve this problem?

Comment: What OS are you using and how did you install pyautogui (`pip install pyautogui` or `pip3 install pyautogui`)?

Comment: I used pip3 install pyautogui

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct python version that matches the pyautogui installation.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same python which is installed by PyCharm? Do you have another Python installed separately from PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working in PyCharm IDE, By Default it creates a **Virtual Env (venv)**. If you had installed packages in your PyCharm IDE. It's scope is limited to that Virtual Environment.

Solution:

While running on CMD terminal or any other linux terminal you've to **PIP install** every package as it'll be then a Global package.

Hope this helps let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you having `ImportError` for `import pyautogui` try this,

[import error for pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635140/import-error-for-pyautogui)

Answer (score 0):

So, I basically was trying to run it in a python 2.X shell. I installed Pyautogui with `pip3 install pyautogui` inside my project folder and ran the program using the command `python3 ./test.py` to run it on a python 3.X shell. Everything works perfectly now! Thank y'all for the help :D

Comment: Just a tip: you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) by clicking the check mark on the left. This is to clearly let future readers, who stumbled upon your answer, know that this is the solution to your problem. :)

Comment: Definitely, I'm just waiting to be able and check my own answer. :D