# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyautogui, modulenotfounderror

I tried installing pyautogui in Visual Studio but whenever I run the following program:

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui #pylint: disable=E0401
import time
import pandas as pd #pylint: disable=E0401
from datetime import datetime

def sign_in(meetingid, pswd):
    # Opens up zoom app
    subprocess.call(r"C:\Users\krish\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Zoom")

sign_in('6931145146', 'SKS123')
```

I get the following error:

```
File "c:\Users\krish\Desktop\AUTOBOT\Zoom Auto Attender", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui #pylint: disable=E0401
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

I tried the available solution [import error for pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635140/import-error-for-pyautogui)

But it doesn't work, So please help.

Comment: How do you know that you installed `pyautogui` to the site-packages directory of the interpreter you use to run your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, please refer to the following:

1. Please use the command "`python --version`" or "`pip --version`" in the VS Code terminal to check whether the python currently used by the VS Code terminal is consistent with the one displayed in the lower left corner of the VS Code.

   [image]

   (If they are inconsistent, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the selected environment.)
2. Check the installation of the module. (`pip show pyautogui`)

   [image]

   The location where VS Code recognizes the python module is in "`\Lib\site-packages\`" of the currently used python environment.

Run:

[image]

Reference: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to install the package for pyautogui

https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

`pip install pyautogui`

Comment: I did it already, terminal says requirement already satisfied

Comment: @krish-del You might want to double-check if the virtualenv you're installing packages into from terminal is the same as the one you're using for the project

Comment: Or if you're using Python 2.*, it will not work. Make sure it's a python 3 environment

Comment: I will make sure of it.

Answer (score 1):

This error can happen if pip installed the module on a version of python which is not the default one. For example, vs code runs a python file on a specific python version but if your default python terminal is different, when you download a module, it will only be downloaded for the python version of your terminal. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njEfK.png)
To verify this error you can enter the command `pip3.9 freeze` and `pip3.10 freeze` to show modules which are installed for a specific python version (I took 3.9 and 3.10 as an example but it's your python versions)

**How to fix it ?**

-change your default vs code interpreter to the default terminal version by clicking Ctrl + Shift + P and typing "interpreter"

-change your default terminal python version : to do so, open your environment variables,then Path, and move up the python path you want to set by default, then save. [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I0i3.png) / [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0JnK.png)

Answer (score 0):

r u sure that u r not in the venv(virtual environment) , if this is not the case
manually install the .whl files go to this site `https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/` and download the wheel files .
and then in the cmd or terminal type
`pip install 'where u have stored the .whl file` 
that should do the work

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem that I have two Python install on my machine. So I remove all of them and reinstall, um and the problem solve.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30711559)